# How can I edit the document title (not filename) and author in Word Online (Microsoft Office)?

Tags: microsoft-word, office365

I'm working on a basic Word template for my organization that's compatible with both the desktop and online (O365) versions of Word. I've simplified most things to work on both platforms, but I'm stuck trying to add a page header that shows the document title. Actually, I can insert a Quick Part to display the document title in the page header... I just can't find any way for the user to actually define/modify the title.

So, is there a way to:

1. Directly edit metadata attributes like the document title and author in Word Online?
2. Add a dynamic field within the document that the user can edit (even in Word Online) that will then write that value to the document title property?

Or is there another way to accomplish this, apart from trying to train our thousands of users that every time they create a document they need to go into OneDrive or SharePoint after to update the metadata there?

Answer (score 0):

### You could perhaps train them to open in the Word application.

I am sorry to be delivering a negative response. Here is a screenshot from a sample document (link below):

[image: screenshot from Word Online]

Here is a temporary [view link](https://1drv.ms/w/s!AvFSGII2xMdrguNgcCKc43lvRb_2NA?e=Jz7ebA) to the above document. The screenshot, showing the active Content Control, is from Word Online. Unfortunately, nothing can be changed in the control. I suspect it can be deleted, but that is hardly the idea.

There is a huge difference in capabilities and features between Word Online and the desktop applications. Here is a [link to MS's list of those differences](https://support.office.com/client/Differences-between-using-a-document-in-the-browser-and-in-Word-3E863CE3-E82C-4211-8F97-5B33C36C55F8), but they are being modest and understating the differences.